# Export multiple Layers at same time to XLSX

Tags: qgis-3

How to export multiple/selected layers to one or more Excel-Sheet?

I do not found an internal function or a plugin for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To export multiple layers to separate spreadsheets**

You can run any tool from the Processing Toolbox in Batch Mode by right clicking on the tool name > Execute as Batch Process... > Choose all your layers, and save them XLSX format. Pick a processing algorithm that doesn't change your layer, for example:

- If your layers are all in the same CRS, use the `Project Layer` tool, and choose the current CRS as the Target CRS.
- Use the `Geometry by Expression` tool, with the expression:

  ```
  $geometry
  ```
- Use the `Order by Expression` tool, with the expression:

  ```
  @row_number
  ```
- `Extract by Location` tool, location is the entire project extent
- `Extract by Expression` tool, expression is `$geometry is not null`
- etc

**Here's an example using the `Project Layer` tool**. I have three layers, called layer1, layer2 and layer3. All of them have the CRS EPSG:4326. I open the Processing Toolbox, find the `Reproject layers` tool, right click on it, and choose "Execute as Batch Process"

[image]

Now the tool is open in Batch Process mode.

- Where the tool says "input layer," I click the `...` button, click "select from open layers", then choose the three layers.

  [image]
- I leave "EPSG:4326" as the Target CRS, because that's the CRS my layers already have and I don't want to change it.
- In the part of the tool where it says "Reprojected", I click the `...` button. Choose the location where I want the output saved, choose the file type XLSX, and type in a file name.

  [image: picture]
- When I click Save, it gives a popup of "autofill settings" - choose "autofill mode: fill with parameter values," and "parameter to use: input layer". This will add the layer name to the file name I just typed.

  [image]

Since the file name I used was "filename" and the layers are called layer1, layer2 and layer3, the output files will be: filenamelayer1.xlsx, and filenamelayer2.xlsx, and filenamelayer3.xlsx.

Here's what the tool looks like at the end:

[image]

Now I click "Run" and each layer is exported to a separate XLSX file.

---

**To export multiple layers to the *same* spreadsheet**

Use the `Merge Vector Layers` in normal mode (not batch processing mode).

- Find the `Merge Vector Layers` tool in the Processing Toolbox. Run the tool. Click the `...` button next to "input layers". Choose the layers you want to combine. Click OK.

  [image]
- Click the `...` button under "merged." Choose the folder where you want the spreadsheet saved, type in a file name, and choose the XLSX file format. Click "save" and "Run."

Comment: I read your answer multiple times but I did not understand any word... ;-)

Comment: I'll add some pictures.

Comment: I added step-by-step instructions with screenshots. Hopefully that makes more sense now.

Comment: Thanks for everything. It works perfect. But it would be cool to have the merged Layers in one file each per worksheet.

Comment: Hint: If your Layer's name have e.g. "/" in it, the filename-filling from the first optionen is not working as expected.

Comment: Of course not. Don't put slashes in your layer names.